# Laravel. MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel

Есть 2 язык. версии на сайте, при активации рус. языка, добавляется в урл "/ru" т.е будет http://site/ru, но при этом, все попытки оправить форму, заканчиваются ошибкой - "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php", на оригинал языки http://site формы нормально работают

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php
in RouteCollection.php line 233
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 220
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 58
```

Файл роутов

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization;



    Route::get('/home', function() {
        return redirect('admin');
    });


    Route::group(
        [
            'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
            'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
        ], function() {

            Route::get('/', 'HomeController@main');

            Route::get('/articles/{start}/{length}', 'ArticleController@api');

            Route::post('/callback', 'ApiController@callback');

            Route::post('/order', 'ApiController@order');

        }
    );
```

Два последних роута под форму

Comment: Покажите файл роутов.

Comment: @Rikaz добавил роуты

Comment: А что находится в параметрах формы? Method, action? А лучше всего код формы полностью.